# Partitioning elements into sets

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, set-partition

How many ways are there to partition $n$ unique elements into $2$ sets? What about for $k$ sets?

I am specifically interested in how to calculate this for varying values of $n$. Moreover, what if there are restrictions, such as the sum of elements in one set must be equal to the sum  of the elements in the other?

Comment: Several rather general questions.  For example the answer to the first might be $2^{n-1}$ or $2^{n-1}-1$ depending on the precise nature of the question. The second question might be related to [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). The answer to the last may depend on the elements, since arbitrary elements do not have sums, while if the elements are integers and add up to an odd number then the answer will be $0$

Answer (score 0):

These are the [Stirling coefficients of the second kind](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmeros_de_Stirling_de_segunda_especie). If the sum of elements in sets must be equal the problem is a lot harder.